# tmux session preview not showing

Tags: terminal, tmux

I am using tmux in a number of machines. I have a weird behavior and I cannot find the reason.

I have a laptop running `tmux 3.0a` and when I do `prefix s` I get the following:

[image]

i.e. a preview of the highlighted session

My desktop machine with `tmux 3.0a` as well has no preview (I have updated to `3.1b` but still nothing):

[image]

Both machines have the same `tmux.conf`

Any ideas?

EDIT: `Toggle preview: v` is not working on my desktop. If I press it the only thing that happens is that the cursor disappears until I move the mouse again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using 3.0a? Check `tmux display -p '#{version}'`. Remember you need to restart tmux entirely (`tmux kill-server`) after upgrading.

Comment: `tmux -V` returns `tmux 3.0a`. 

`tmux display -p '#{version}'` returns `master`. 

Could it be because my `zsh` version is older than the one in my laptop?

Comment: Laptop: `tmux -V` returns `tmux 3.0a`.  `tmux display -p '#{version}'` returns `2.8`

Comment: `tmux -V` shows the version you have installed on disk but `tmux display -p '#{version}'` shows the version that is running. You need to kill tmux and start it again using the new version, you can kill it completely by running `tmux kill-server`.

Comment: I know about `tmux kill-server` and I have already used it. Looks like I had to update the path on my panel icon to point to the 3.0a tmux